# Executing Oracle stored proc in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, dataframe

Currently I am executing an oracle stored proc in python using cx_Oracle package and then converting the cursor to excel using pandas dataframes.

```py
cur = con.cursor() 
myvar = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
cur.callfunc(func_name, myvar,param_list) 
data = myvar.getvalue().fetchall() 

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%I_%M_%S_%p") 
xlsfilename = f"STOCK_DETAIL_REPORT_{filepart}_{date}.xlsx" 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsfilename, engine='xlsxwriter') df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=func_name.split(".")[1], header=False, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Want to know if there is some option in python pandas itself to execute the stored proc convert that into dataframes?

Comment: Please reformat your code. Use code formatting, not quotation.

Comment: You state that you execute procedure, but your code executes function. Does it return cursor or collection?

Comment: You will have to write a *wrapper* function *fetching the ref cursor and returning a table type* as described [here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/888365/pl-sql-101-understanding-ref-cursors) to be able to get the result with a SQL query.

Comment: Another piped example is in rc2pipeline.sql on p202 of [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/underground-php-oracle-manual.html).  You can see the final application code (which would be Python in your case), does a SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can see in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql) Pandas `pd.read_sql` does not support running stored procedures.